# How to create a menu call?

Tags: material-design-lite

How to create a menu call as the left menu in this site:
http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#toggles-section

Can somebody tell me a documentation of this kind of implementation?

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You find a detailed explanation and code examples on the website under "Layout": http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/layout

Answer (score 0):

The drawer component of the layout is what we provide for site navigation. The side menu on the documentation site is custom. If you wish you could reverse-engineer the code out, but it isn't something supported.